# How can I escape characters using ASCII 3-letter codes?

Tags: c++, c, escaping, ascii, non-printing-characters

I want something like

```
 string magic(char c);
```

so that when I do

```
 std::cout << magic(c);
```

I get:

- The character itself for printing ASCII characters;
- A 2/3-letter ASCII code for other ASCII characters (e.g. `"NUL"`, `"BEL"`, `"LF"` etc.)
- Anything reasonable when c is non-ASCII (8th bit on).

What should I use? (It doesn't have to be a function necessarily.)

Comment: If you want the output to be printable ASCII, you need at least one printable ASCII character to be mangled/escaped into two or three printable ASCII chars. Unless you want ambiguity.

Comment: Do you want that to work everywhere (ebcdic computers included)?

Comment: @einpoklum: Why not write it yourself? As long it´s only ASCII (not Unicode-stuff, EBCDIC or something even stranger), the control character amount is small. Just some if-else and an array of special names like "BEL"...

Comment: @delnan: Not necessarily... I can tell results apart by space, or using a field width etc.

Comment: @pmg: No need to get crazy... :-)

Comment: @deviantfan: Because I want to use common library code rather than write my own, if possible. Of course I can just write it myself.

Comment: @einpoklum: I don´t think there is any lib function for this.

Comment: Could you use a simple look-up table? `const char *magic[] = {"NUL", "SOH" ... "a", "b" ... "0xFE", "0xFF" };`.

Comment: Simplest would be to copy the implementation of `od -t a` ("named character") from whatever source code (GNU coreutils, BSD, AST) has the copyright you like best. The names of ASCII codes can be found on the [od man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/od.html). In GNU coreutils, the appropriate function is `print_named_ascii()` in `src/od.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Combining @Pter and @deviantfan's comments:

There's apparently no common library functionality for achieving this. A simple implementation would involve a lookup table for the low ASCII value, and a check for the 8th bit; an even simpler implementation would involve a lookup table for all 256 values.